# How do I get the numerical value/position of a character in the alphabet (1-26) in constant time (O(1)) without using any built in method or function?

Tags: java, c++, c, algorithm

How do I get the numerical value/position of a character in the alphabet (1-26) in constant time (O(1)) without using any built in method or function and without caring about the case of the character?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your compiler supports binary literals you can use

```
int value = 0b00011111 & character;
```

If it does not, you can use 31 instead of 0b00011111 since they are equivalent.

```
int value = 31 & character;
```

or if you want to use hex

```
int value = 0x1F & character;
```

or in octal

```
int value = 037 & character;
```

You can use any way to represent the value 31.

This works because in ASCII, undercase values are prefixed with 011, and uppercase 010 and then the binary equivalent of 1-26. 
By using the bitmask of 00011111 and the AND operand, we covert the 3 most significant bits to zeros. This leaves us with 00001 to 11010, 1 to 26.

Comment: If the language doesn't support binary literals you can still use 0x1F.

Comment: or 31, as stated in my answer, but yeah, hexadecimal works as well. Pretty much any way you can represent 31 will work.

Comment: I didn't see that part of your answer.  I should be careful about posting this late at night :(

Comment: You are mapping (a-z) to (0-25). You must add 1 to the value.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to the [very good (self) answer of Charles Staal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284070/how-do-i-get-the-numerical-value-position-of-a-character-in-the-alphabet-1-26/31284071#31284071).

Assuming ascii encoding following will work. Updated from the kind comment of [Yves Daoust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284070/how-do-i-get-the-numerical-value-position-of-a-character-in-the-alphabet-1-26/31284117#comment50568018_31284117)

```
int Get1BasedIndex(char ch) {
  return ( ch | ('a' ^ 'A') ) - 'a' + 1;
}
```

This will make the character uppercase and change the index.

However a more readable solution (`O(1)`) is:

```
int Get1BasedIndex(char ch) {
  return ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') ? ch - 'a' + 1 : ch - 'A' + 1;
}
```

One more solution that is constant time but requires some extra memory is:

```
static int cha[256];

static void init() {
  int code = -1;
  fill_n (&cha[0], &cha[256], code);
  code = 1;
  for(char s = 'a', l = 'A'; s <= 'z'; ++s, ++l) {
    cha[s] = cha[l] = code++;
  }
}

int Get1BasedIndex(char ch) {
  return cha[ch];
}
```

Comment: `return ( ch & ~('a' ^ 'A') ) - 'A' + 1;` ... why would you write anything like that?

Comment: This takes significantly more time than the answer first posted. By adding more math than just 1 AND operation, you may as well check case and -64 or -96 from the value.

Comment: @immibis Instead of using any ascii code, I prefferred `'a' ^ 'A'` which most compiler should be able to constant fold.

Comment: @CharlesStaal You are right, moreover the second answer is not constant time. But it is surely more readable and can be maintained easily. I proposed 3 solutions and each has its own pros and cons.

Comment: Well I asked the question and answered it so people can be educated about how the ASCII table is laid out and why it is laid out the way it is. Also, to show people that bitwise operations are not useless, that they are powerful and very useful.

Comment: Exactly, and I did not want to copy your `self answer` thus added a few more possibilities.

Comment: "O(1) but not constant time" so what is constant time then, if not O(1) time?

Comment: @MohitJain: I love the way in which you expressed the "Shift" bit mask. Forcing conversion to lowercase is slightly shorter: `ch | ('a' ^ 'A') - 'a' + 1`.

Comment: @NiklasB. Yes you are right, fixed. I meant run time may vary for different inputs in version 2. While in version 1 and version 3, time consumed would be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

We can get their ASCII values and then subtract from the starting character ASCII(`a - 97, A - 65`)

```
 char ch = 'a';
    if(ch >=65 && ch <= 90)//if capital letter
        System.out.println((int)ch - 65);
    else if(ch >=97 && ch <= 122)//if small letters
        System.out.println((int)ch - 97);
```